# Shapefile to Rectangle Overlay/Intersect Test?

Tags: shapefile, c#

I have a shapefile and a repository of images that have corner Lat/Long points. I want to search that images who overlaps/intersects to shapefile.

Here is the scenario that I am doing, creating a polygon from each image corner lat/long points and placing it in temporary memory.

Now how can I check whether this created polygon intersects/overlaps the shapefile?

Any solution recommended for this issue?

Comment: do you need a c# solution or are other languages/softwares OK ?

Comment: Thanks radouxju for the reply. I am developing a desktop application in c#. So requires c# solution for the mentioned scenario.

Comment: GDAL can be used via C# bindings http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp and MapWindow http://mapwindow.org/ is all C# and may provide some examples or usable components for you. About how to find the intersecting polygons, you must find somewhere the same functionality than ST_Intersects http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html.

Comment: Thanks. I will let them implement. Is it good procedure that I have to first create a shape-file from geo-spacial image corner vertices and then use ST_Intersects method to find out whether this shape-file is intersecting the other?

Comment: I can't say really. But if you will have millions of images then it would be good to store the footprints so that you can create spatial index for them. That will make intersects queries faster.

Comment: ok. My application have two parts front end and back end. In front end there is user interface where is shapefile is provided and database of geo spatial images is in back end. i am using sql server 2012. I have already tested Point In shape file using DotSpatial but there are some images whose vertices are not coming inside provided shapefile. So i have to search shapefile intersection but cant find that in Dotspatial. I have also search Mapwindow and found [link](http://www.mapwindow.org/phorum/read.php?3,24042,printview,page=1) but not a clear solution.

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that can be used to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Potential answerers who are all volunteers do not always have time to read comments so anything important should always be in the question body.